# Import Data from SQL into Excel and then auto refresh using PYTHON

Tags: python, sql, excel

I have an excel workbook with 14 sheets for data and more 8 tabs for the report views.

Objective: To be able to populate all the 14 sheets of data from 14 different SQL tables and hide them. Then auto refresh the pivot views in the                        next 8 tabs

Challenge: I am using pyodbc and pandas to import data from SQL but I am unable to unhide the hidden 14 data tabs and delete the old data and then paste the new data and then again hide the data sheets.
Also, I am unable to automatically refresh the pivots in the other tabs without having to manually click refresh.

Any help with a code with dummy excel sheet will be very helpful.

Comment: Would you be able to share some of the code you have tried to manipulate the Excel? That way we can get a better idea of what you are trying to do.

Comment: I am currently travelling so do not have access to the code sadly till next Monday. I will be in office from then and was hoping if any idea can help me out with it than it will be great. For further clarification though:
I have an excel workbook where I need to unhide 8 sheets and than delete the old data and than paste data from SQL server from 8 sources and than hide it.
Post this is done I am trying to auto refresh the pivots the in the other tabs.
I have been able to successfully paste data from SQL but I am unable to hide/unhide the sheets as well as auto refresh the data in pivots